# Вывод блока во время выполнения скрипта

Tags: javascript

Пробовал сделать так:

```
.disp-none { display:none;}
......
var block= document.getElementById("progress-bar");
block.classList.add("disp-none");
btn.onclick = function() 
{
   block.classList.remove("disp-none");
   draw();
   block.classList.add("disp-none");
}
```

Скрипт выполняется секунд 10, формируется изображение в канвасе. Проблема в том, пока выполняется скрипт блок не появляется. Видимо во время работы скрипта html код не меняется(класс disp-none не удаляется). Что делать в таком случае, как вывести блок перед работой скрипта и спрятать после. Без jQuery

```
function draw(callback) 
{

let fill_bar = block.querySelector(".fill");
let width = 0;

requestAnimationFrame(fill);
function fill() 
{
    width += 1;
    fill_bar.style.width = width + "%";

    if( width >= 2 ) 
    {
    if(callback) 
        callback();
        redraw();

        return; // Анимация в любом случае завершается, с вызовом функции или без.
    }
requestAnimationFrame(fill);
  }
}
```

Этот код работает, здесь выполняется функция redraw, которая раньше у меня была draw. Но здесь я так понимаю лишнего много, увелечение ширины например. Как лишнее убрать, что бы работоспособность осталась?

```
function draw(callback) 
{
requestAnimationFrame(fill);
function fill() 
{
    redraw();
    if(callback) 
        callback();
}
}
```

Так не работает

Comment: О_о а зачем туда добавлять ширину, если она не нужна?) Это у меня был всего лишь пример условия, которое сообщает о завершении отрисовки. Что-то похожее же есть внутри redraw, которое заканчивает рисование?

Comment: нету, ширина не нужна, не знаю как избавиться от нее =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Видимо во время работы скрипта html код не меняется

```
block.classList.add("disp-none");
block.classList.remove("disp-none");
block.classList.add("disp-none");
```

Даже если написать три таких строчки подряд, браузер не станет скрывать, показывать, потом снова скрывать блок. Код выполняется настолько быстро, что к моменту начала отрисовки блока, он сразу будет с классом "disp-none". А в вашем случае, вы всего лишь добавили еще одну строчку `draw()` которая погоду не меняет: Если он асинхронный, скрипт не обязан тратить время на ожидание его выполнения. Просто запускает функцию и идет дальше выполнять код.

В качестве аргумента draw() можно передать обычную функцию, которую он будет вызывать при завершении анимации:

```js
var block = document.getElementById("progress-bar");

block.classList.add("hide");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  block.classList.remove("hide");

  function onAnimationEnd() {
    block.classList.add("hide");
    console.log("Завершилось!");
  }

  draw(onAnimationEnd);
});

/***/

function draw(callback) {
  let fill_bar = block.querySelector(".fill");
  let width = 0;

  requestAnimationFrame(fill);
  function fill() {
    width += 1;
    fill_bar.style.width = width + "%";
    
    if( width >= 100 ) {
      if(callback) callback();
      return; // Анимация в любом случае завершается, с вызовом функции или без.
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(fill);
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Test</button>
<hr>
<div id="progress-bar">
  <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не работает. Функция draw ведет расчеты и отрисовку, не связанную с прогресс баром. Этот расчет занимает некоторое время. Когда нажимается кнопка, необходимо, что бы блок появился и пропал после выполнения скрипта.

Comment: @helldrg "Не работает" - понятие широкое) Всё равно же можно контролировать расчеты в любой функции и понимать, в каком месте она завершается. Добавьте тогда код функции-рисовашки в вопрос, надо значит смотреть на него...

Comment: где то пол часа назад получилось желаемого эффекта достичь благодаря Вам. Спасибо большое!!! Не особо понятно как это работает, но работает)

Comment: а как изменить функцию fill, чтобы ширина не увеличивалась, а просто одна функция выполнялась и все

Comment: Добавил в конце вопроса код

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте функцию канвас-отрисовки асинхронной: `const draw = async () => {...}`

Comment: Там же еще нужно await куда-нибудь добавить?)

Comment: все равно скрипт выполняется, а блок не появляется

Comment: Да, я теперь, кажется, понял соль проблемы. Правильней всего будет сделать всю вашу главную функцию асинхронной, чтобы она никогда не блокировала поток. Затем, как выше верно подметил трансформер, прицепить к вызову draw `await` (и переменную результата, следовательно). Все тогда должно пойти хорошо. А еще, в качестве совета, - лучше использовать не `elem.onclick = function() {...}`, а `elem.addEventListener('click', ()=>{...})`.

Comment: Проверьте этот вариант, если получится, обновлю свой ответ

Comment: Не работает. Дополнил вопрос кодом попытки. Может что то не так понял я

Comment: Да, вы не совсем поняли. Нужно сделать асинхронной самую главную функцию, в которой у вас происходят манипуляции с DOM и вызов draw(). И непосредственно вызов draw() представить, как `let result = await draw()`

Comment: Не работает. Дополнил вопрос попыткой

Comment: Просто не работает, или выбрасывает ошибки? Вы, в целом, уверенны, что отрисовка нормально работает и что она выполняется длительное время? Что стили у элемента block по дефолту в порядке и что класс с `display: none;` точно не применяется (запустите скрипт - и проверяйте стили в консоли). Также можете посмотреть, в каком виде консоль выдаст элемент после первой инструкции с ремувом в обработчике клика (добавьте после нее `console.log(block)` и запустите скрипт). Все это - потому что лично я не вижу больше возможных ошибок в самом коде.

Comment: в функции draw формируется канвас размером 15к на 15к, пока он не сформируется DOM элементы не обновляются. Так же выводить через блок в канвасе не имеется возможным, потому что он скрыт